# What does the number after the -f flag in grep mean?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

```
./sum.sh "`grep -w "numpeople:" *.ord | cut -d":" -f3`"
```

All the *.ord files are from the template:

```
numpeople: 3
steak
steak
salad
mushrooms
salad
salad
soup
```

After the ":" could be any number of spaces and also after it:

```
numpeople:              3 
numpeople:       3
```

My question:

How does this stroke, and more accurately, how does the -f3 makes this command take the 3 from the cutt line if there is different number of spaces ?

If this help's anybody:

```
#!bin/bash
for cur_num in $1; do
    (( sum+=cur_num ))
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: Show the source of sum.sh

Comment: I don't think it matter. A simple sum script, simplest as you can think about.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I though the whole statement would be passed to the sum.sh as an argument, I didn't noticed the back ticks at first. But how is it possible that `grep -w "num people:"` selects "numpeople:" in your example?

Comment: Why shouldn't it, if you ask, you may explain your question, because I don't see a reason it it shouldn't. The grep choose all the files with this words and then cut's the non-important and left only spaces with number somewhere. After that I don't understand how it find accurately the number.

Comment: It should not, because "num people" is not "numpeople". Also `cut -d : -f 3` makes no sense for me, because `-d :` selects colon as a field delimiter, and `-f 3` means "field 3". Bu in your example are only two fields: one is "numpeople", and the second is "3".

Comment: oh, that's true, that was a typo. But stil you do right, that's why I don't understand eather, how count the fields. Because the mister, which answered down-below didn't say about this anything.

Answer (score 1):

there was no -f3 in grep. it is in cut command. it means "field 3" . ie. anything after second ":" and before third ":" in the data lines. generally fields are space delimited, but here -d: is used to indicate ":" is used to separate.

Comment: ok, that make sense, and why 3-rd field, what are the 2 previous, if you can mark them? Or why after the second or third? it is the first ":" that after it the number is  there' isn't it ?

Comment: To elaborate more, first grep command selects 'only rows that has this "num people"' and passes the result to cut command. Second, cut command filters out only third filed, considering ":" (not space) as field separator.

To understand what is happening to the data, run this first and observe the output:
grep -w "num people:" *.ord 
Then run this next:
grep -w "num people:" *.ord  | cut -d":" -f3

Then you can ask what is misleading you.

Comment: Yes, i'm understand what do the separate parts, just don't see how the enumeration of the field is making it the third ) 
the ":" is the first and the spaces are the second ? That's how you count and enumarate the fields ?

Comment: I am surprised too. That is why I am asking to show out put of this:
 `grep -w "num people:" *.ord | cut -d":" -f3`
if the above is empty then,
`grep -w "num people:" *.ord `

Comment: first (3rd copy).ord:numpeople: 3 first (4th copy).ord:numpeople: 3 first (5th copy).ord:numpeople: 3 first (another copy).ord:numpeople: 3 first (copy).ord:numpeople: 3 first.ord:numpeople: 3

Comment: that is the result of 

grep -w "num people:" *.ord, it does work like this correctly

Comment: yes, the first field is the name of the file, the second is the numpeople and the 3 is the number. strange. it is suprising

Comment: Now I get the point.
The number field is the second (after first ":") in the files.
Because the grep output adds another "<filename> : " in first palce, with that extra ":" the number field is pushed to third place. So the cut command uses -f3.